# Creating Advanced Gantt Chart

Tags: c#, forms, controls, runtime, gantt-chart

I am workin on an automation of production follow-up project with c# and we are producing fabric. and we have many customers and their works are running on about 100 weaving machines. 
so there is a planning departman and they are deciding to optimum time-save and many time one customers product weaving on multiple machines. 
This excel sheet capture shows which machine work wich job and will work after current work. and user can carry the work if she decide to carry to another machine.

in thispicture first line is date line and different colors are different works...

[image]

I want a gantt chart as flexible as this. are there any solution for it?

Comment: There's a whole lot of 3rd party components for creating charts. Did you already do some research?

Comment: yes I research a lot of gantt component. and all of them are work one job on one line. but I want more job planning on each machines

Answer (score 1):

I think, your task has two facets: there is a scheduling challenge (time-optimized allocation of the production flow) and a visualization challenge (display the plan on a comprehensive screen). If you go for a Gantt chart to cope with the visualization challenge, make sure that it is interactive and allows the planner to make changes on the screen and that these changes are written back into your planning system. Also, the Gantt should be open and flexible enough to deal with business rules so that the outer appearance can be context-sensitive. Here is an example of how a Gantt chart can work in a production environment: http://youtu.be/oXRUy90lpsM

Does this help you?

Comment: that's exactly what I want but it work on vs2010 I think. I will work on this solution.

Answer (score 0):

There's a commercial component for creating such charts with quite good documentation from [PlexityHide](http://www.plexityhide.com/). But you can also use e.g. a general charting framework such as the [Microsoft Chart Controls](http://archive.msdn.microsoft.com/mschart) to recreate what you want. Certainly there are several more.

Answer (score 0):

Here's some getting-started 
http://www.codeproject.com/KB/webforms/EventCalendarControl.aspx 
http://naspinski.net/post/Simple-Gantt-Chart-with-Aspnet.aspx 

Or use ZedGraph:
http://sourceforge.net/projects/zedgraph/
http://www.codeproject.com/KB/web-image/ZedGraph.aspx

Also, MS-Chart controls is nice.
See here to get started: 
http://weblogs.asp.net/scottgu/archive/2008/11/24/new-asp-net-charting-control-lt-asp-chart-runat-quot-server-quot-gt.aspx

Answer (score 0):

There is a very good Production Planning online sample here which lets you drag and drop color coded tasks from one machine to another:
http://demos.radiantq.com/jQueryGanttDemo/Demo.htm

There is also .NET versions of the Gantt component which lets you build something similar in a desktop application.